# I've got an adb error as soon as I try to run my app on 5 emulators at the same time

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've developed an app and I've been testing it on 4 emulators at the same time. Now I tried to launch the app on a 5th emulator and I get this error on the eclipse console:

> [2011-10-06 21:38:49 - adb]This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>
> [2011-10-06 21:38:49 - adb]Please contact the application's support team for more information.
>
> [2011-10-06 21:39:04 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:Uma ligação existente foi forçada a fechar pelo anfitrião remoto

Translation of the last error message: *An existing connection was forced to close by the remote host*

The app works on a client-server architecture, but this error comes up as soon the app is launched so, no connection is yet created.

I am able to run the app on the 5 emulators, but this way I don't have LogCat to monitor my debug prints.

I need to test it on 10 emulators. My pc has an i5 750 processor @ 3.6 GHz and 4 GB RAM, so it should be able to run 5 emulators, each one using only 256 MB...

What can I do?

Comment: I translated the error message and then Googled a little bit, and most similar errors that popped up involved trying to attach adb to code running on real devices that had specific versions of Android running.  Can you connect adb to the 5th emulator if it's the only emulator?  It might be the AVD profile and not the number of devices.  Seems to be adb issues with newer version of Android that Google knows about but hasn't fixed yet.

Comment: I'm running the app on local emulators, not on real devices, don't know if that was clear. Anyway, every emulator is using the same profile, android 2.1, so it's not the case of the 5th emulator running a different version of android. I'm going to translate the error message on the original post so it might be easier to others.

Comment: Just tried changing the avd profile targets to android 2.2 and now I can only have 3 emulators running...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I recognized that you were using the virtual devices.  I was just saying that most other occurrences of this problem had been on real devices.